# How to get unique records of a datetime column of data table with a margin of 60 seconds?

Tags: c#, asp.net, datetime, datatable

I have a datatable in c# that contains a column with date time values. I want to get the distinct values with a margin of 60 seconds.

My current code is like this:

```
  string[] distinctCols = { "AssetId", "LDOM" };
  DataTable distinctAssetId = dt.DefaultView.ToTable(true, distinctCols);
```

This is working absolutely fine and giving me unique records. However, I need unique records with a margin of 60 seconds.

For example, the LDOM Values of "06-11-2013 12:56:01" & "06-11-2013 12:56:00" should be considered as unique.

How do I achieve this.

Comment: Is `distint` a typo  (`distinct`)? You want distinct within the range? why aren't they distinct to begin with (they have different dates, they are distinct ...) ? If you're looking for all dates within 60 seconds, how do you split the start/end?

Comment: @Noctis, yeah I think the spelling is incorrect. Yes I want distinct but with a range. Finding distinct is not a problem. I am facing problem in finding distinct within a range/margin of 60 seconds.

Comment: why? how do you search? can't you look for bigger and smaller than? (either sql, linq, method that look at dates, etc)

Comment: You probably need to use a different method, ToTable doesn't let you define more than which columns and whether or not it should be distinct. You could fill the datatable from a dataadapter so that you can write the SQL command yourself.

Comment: If `06-11-2013 12:56:01` and `06-11-2013 12:56:00` should be considered as the same which value do you want to return?

Comment: @Magnus, anyone. Doesnt matter.

Comment: What about 12:55:05, 12:56:00 and 12:56:55? do you want them all together?

Comment: @XavierPoinas, I know its never going to be like you have mentioned. However, even in case it is, i want all the 12:55:05, 12:56:00 and 12:56:55 together in one row.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example of how it can be done:

```
var dates = new[] 
    { 
        new DateTime(2013, 11, 6, 12, 56, 1),
        new DateTime(2013, 11, 6, 12, 56, 0),  
        new DateTime(2013, 11, 6, 12, 56, 50),  
        new DateTime(2013, 11, 6, 12, 10, 0)  
    };
var q = dates.GroupBy(d => d.Ticks / TimeSpan.TicksPerMinute)
       .Select(g => g.First());
```

This will return:

```
2013-11-06 12:56:01
2013-11-06 12:10:00
```

You should have not problem applying the same technique with a DataTable column using linq.